# Checking the value in the argument passed to a function

Tags: bash, shell, csh

When i try to log the argument i get the right value . How do i compare if an argument is a particular string in csh script. And what is the corresponding code in bash.

```
checkstatus()
{
  /bin/echo $1 >> outfile.txt

if ["$1" = "show"]
then
    /bin/echo "it is show" >> outfile.txt
else
    /bin/echo "it is not show" >> outfile.txt
fi
}


checkstatus show
```

I get show in output file but the false case in if condition. Must be a easy one that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash it works if you (1) add a space around the "[]" brackets and (2) use "==" instead of "=":

```
if [ "$1" == "show" ]
```

(2) isn't strictly necessary, but a bit clearer, since "=" is typically used as assignment operator.

Comment: Since `==` gives up POSIX compliance, you may as well switch to `[[ ... ]]` as well instead of the old-style `[ ... ]` expression.